# change the range of axis to non continuous number in Matplotlib plotting

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe, the 'x' column is like [8, 9, 10, ..., 24, 1, 2, 3, ..., 7]. When I try to plot it, the x axis will still start from 1, 2, 3, ... Could I change it as start from 8 to 24, then 1 to 7? The code is as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l1 = [x for x in range(1, 25)]
l2 = l1[7:] + l1[:7]
arr1 = np.asarray(l2)
arr1

y = np.random.rand(24)

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': arr1, 'y': y})

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.bar(df['x'],df['y'])
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)

plt.show()

print(df)

     x         y
0    8  0.354536
1    9  0.418379
2   10  0.902957
3   11  0.026550
4   12  0.560771
5   13  0.804618
6   14  0.114657
7   15  0.969412
8   16  0.595874
9   17  0.193734
10  18  0.740406
11  19  0.848634
12  20  0.799882
13  21  0.674117
14  22  0.453562
15  23  0.009416
16  24  0.124332
17   1  0.232094
18   2  0.405055
19   3  0.034836
20   4  0.627928
21   5  0.347363
22   6  0.170759
23   7  0.084413
```

Comment: There are two options essentially. (1) Fake the axis units by plotting the index and setting the ticklabels to the shifted numbers. (2) Truely change the axis units. Not sure what you're after here.

Comment: think the first is good enough for me, I just want to start the unit from the middle (8 in this example)

Comment: I think I have to truly change the axis unit, just change the display of the ticklabels would shift the plotting in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need this:

```
ax.bar(np.arange(len(df)), df['y'])
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(df)))
ax.set_xticklabels(df['x'])
```

Comment: Thanks! @Julien it works great for me! But could I ask why "ax.set_xticklabels(df['x'])" would not work and have to add the line "ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(df)))"?

Comment: This is to specify the location of your ticks. If you don't do it it will use default settings which will screw you up.

Comment: alright, got it now. thanks so much for your explanation!~

Comment: Hi @Julien I found a problem for this. It only change the display of the x axis, but not really changing the plot

Comment: Not sure what you mean... Why should it "change the plot"?

Comment: I need my plotting really start from ('x'=)8, not just the display of the axis value.

Comment: "ax.set_xticklabels(df['x'])" just change the label of the x-axis(e.g., 8), but the actual plotting does not change(still from 1)

Comment: It is easy in other drawing programs like excel as my first point of is (8, 0.5)(x axis, y axis), the x axis will start from 8. But in matplotlib, even (8, 0.5) is the first point, if I have the point (1, 0.65) in the middle, the x axis will start from 1 any way

Comment: Well that's a completely different problem, and it is solved using `set_xlim(xmin, xmax)`. If not I just don't understand what you are trying to achieve, maybe you need to share a drawing of expected results or something a bit clearer than words...

Comment: Hi @julien the problem of "set_xlim(min, max)" is that the number has to be keep going up or going down. My x axis is from 8 to 24 then 1 to 7 (the meaning of this number is hour, so it is from morning to night actually)

Answer (score 0):

so after several try I figure it out the problem. My problem is my want to plot with discontinous axis unit(not break), the figure I want is the one at the bottom (from 5 to 10 then back from 1 to 4)

[image]

following is the code with the great help of @Julien

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#generate data for 'x' column
list_x = [x for x in range(1, 11)]
arrX = np.asarray(list_x)

#generate data for 'y' column
list_y = [i for i in range(10, 110, 10)]
arrY = np.asarray(list_y)

#generate the dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': arrX, 'y': arrY})

df2 = pd.concat([df1[4:],df1[:4]])
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)

print(df1)
print(df2)

fig = plt.figure(dpi=128, figsize=(6, 6))
ax1, ax2 = fig.add_subplot(211), fig.add_subplot(212)

ax1.bar(np.arange(len(df1)), df1['y'])
ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(len(df1)))
ax1.set_xticklabels(df1['x'])

ax2.bar(np.arange(len(df2)), df2['y'])
# ax2.bar(df2['x'], df2['y'])  ## this will not work. Has to use the code above

# @Julien provides the following to modify the label
ax2.set_xticks(np.arange(len(df2)))
ax2.set_xticklabels(df2['x'])


plt.show()
```